# How do I get results from dynamically created radio buttons?

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

**EDIT* I tried the suggested changes in the first answer but I was getting radio buttons that could be chosen more than once and the label number was controlling the top radio button.  Since then I've tinkered..I'll do my best to explain.*

I'm new to Razor Pages and .Net and I've set myself a project where I create questions and their Category and Display Order into a table in SQL i.e. Order: 1 Category: 'Azure' Question: 'Rate your knowledge on Azure Databricks'

In a separate Page I am then pulling the list of questions in on a @foreach.  This results in a Web page with Category, Questions and Radio Buttons in order.  I have 5 Radio Buttons being inserted below each questions and Radios play nicely with each other, but on clicking the Submit button it just brings (inserts into my table) 1 blank record.

Here's a shortened version of the code:

I want to (get question details from table [Category] > Create Question page > Collate RadioButton Entries into [Category2] table)

Edited version

```
using GaryGaryGary.BaconModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using BaconDataAccess;
using BaconModels;

namespace GaryGaryGary.Pages.Questions
{
[BindProperties]
public class QuestionsModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;


    public QuestionsModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    //These lists are pulled out of the Categpory table and displayed as Questions in the Questions Page
    public IEnumerable<Category> Web { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Agile { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Code { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Testing { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Microsoft { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> Azure { get; set; }
   


    //Pulling the Lists and using lambda to organise them into an order, as per the table they are coming from
    public async Task OnGet()
    {

        Web = await _db.Category.Where(x => x.Skill == "Web").OrderBy(s => s.DisplayOrder).ToListAsync();
        Agile = await _db.Category.Where(x => x.Skill == "Agile").OrderBy(s => s.DisplayOrder).ToListAsync();
        Code = await _db.Category.Where(x => x.Skill == "Code").OrderBy(s => s.DisplayOrder).ToListAsync();
        Testing = await _db.Category.Where(x => x.Skill == "Testing").OrderBy(s => s.DisplayOrder).ToListAsync();
        Microsoft = await _db.Category.Where(x => x.Skill == "Microsoft").OrderBy(s => s.DisplayOrder).ToListAsync();
        Azure = await _db.Category.Where(x => x.Skill == "Azure").OrderBy(s => s.DisplayOrder).ToListAsync();
      

    }


    //This is where I want to send the Data to.  Currently the receiving Category2 table has the same column setup as the Category table.
    //This does grab the username and role as long as no Radios are chosen???  Feeling very out of my depth
    [BindProperty]
    public Category2 Category2 { get; set; }
 


   
    ///in this bit I now want to catch all of the entries made into the Radio buttons as well the User Name and Department > See HTML

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            return Page();
        }

      
        await _db.Category2.AddAsync(Category2);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("../Index");
    }


    
  }
 }
```

```html
@page  
@model GaryGaryGary.Pages.Questions.QuestionsModel
@{
}
<div>
<h1 class="text-center text-green">Project Questionnaire</h1>
<br />  
</div>  
 <form asp-action="Submit" asp-controller="Questions">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
               <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
                <label asp-for="Category2.User" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Category2.User" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Category2.User" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
                <label asp-for="Category2.Role" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Category2.Role" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Category2.Role" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
   @*// I would like for the above (Username and Role) to get carried into the table along with the corresponding answers .  Should it be in the loop to and hidden maybe?   *@      
           
       <h1 class="text-warning">Azure and Cloud Applications </h1>
@{
    int i=0;           //Index gets added as per 1st Answer
    int j = 0;           //Index gets added as per 1st Answer
}

@*The foreach grabs the list from the code behind and uses it to display the order number and question.  5 Radio buttons then follow.  In this example I tried naming the group Category2 but I've tried all sorts.  So confused?*@
@foreach (var obj in Model.Azure)
{
    <fieldset class="ml-3 form-group">
        <legend>@obj.DisplayOrder : @obj.Question </legend>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">      
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option1" type="radio" name="Category2[@i]" class="form-check-input"  value="r1">
            <label id="Azure1">1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option2" type="radio" name="Category2[@i]" class="form-check-input"  value="r2">
            <label id="Azure2">2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option3" type="radio" name="Category2[@i]" class="form-check-input"  value="r3">
            <label id="Azure3">3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option4" type="radio" name="Category2[@i]" class="form-check-input"  value="r4">
            <label id="Azure4">4</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option5" type="radio" name="Category2[@i]" class="form-check-input" value="r5">
            <label id="Azure5">5</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    i++;     //Index counts each loop 
}
<br />
@*Next foreach group does the same for the next topic.  Here I added .a to the name becuase otherwise all Radio buttons are grouped and start arguing. If I gave them a unique name, how do I then grab that info?*@
<h1 class="text-warning">⛅ Web and Cloud Knowledge </h1>
@foreach (var obj in Model.Web)
{
    <fieldset class="ml-3 form-group">
        <legend>@obj.DisplayOrder : @obj.Question </legend>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">     
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option1" type="radio" name="Category2[@j].a" class="form-check-input"  value="r1">
            <label id="WebResult1">1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option2" type="radio" name="Category2[@j].a" class="form-check-input"  value="r2">
            <label id="WebResult2">2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option3" type="radio" name="Category2[@j].a" class="form-check-input"  value="r3">
            <label id="WebResult3">3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option4" type="radio" name="Category2[@j].a" class="form-check-input"  value="r4">
            <label id="WebResult4">4</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option5" type="radio" name="Category2[@j].a" class="form-check-input" value="r5">
            <label id="WebResult5">5</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    j++;   //Index counts each loop 
}     
<br />    
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
    
        
@*They'll be a few more foreach loop lists to come that will pick up the other lists from the page control*@
```

Happy to provide code from elsewhere (table setup etc.) if required, and comfortable with creating a new table to receive the results.  Currently the receiving table is setup with the same model as the table holding the questions but I can't get anything worth while back from the questions page?  This is my first time at doing this so apologies if there is any bad code or practice.

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/radios. Note in particular the role that the radio's `name` attribute plays.

Answer (score 1):

Model binding binds the property by name attribute. Your name attribute does not match the backend propety.

```
@{
    int i=0;           //add index...
    int j = 0;
}
@foreach (var obj in Model.Azure)
{
    <fieldset class="ml-3 form-group">
        <legend>@obj.DisplayOrder : @obj.Question </legend>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">       //change all the name attributes...
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option1" type="radio" name="Azure[@i].Option1" class="form-check-input"  value="r1">
            <label id="Azure" asp-for="Category2.Option1">1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option2" type="radio" name="Azure[@i].Option2" class="form-check-input"  value="r2">
            <label id="Azure" asp-for="Category2.Option2">2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option3" type="radio" name="Azure[@i].Option3" class="form-check-input"  value="r3">
            <label id="Azure" asp-for="Category2.Option3">3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option4" type="radio" name="Azure[@i].Option4" class="form-check-input"  value="r4">
            <label id="Azure" asp-for="Category2.Option4">4</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option5" type="radio" name="Azure[@i].Option5" class="form-check-input" value="r5">
            <label id="Azure" asp-for="Category2.Option5">5</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    i++;     //add this.....
}

<h1 class="text-warning">Web Knowledge </h1>
@foreach (var obj in Model.Web)
{
    <fieldset class="ml-3 form-group">
        <legend>@obj.DisplayOrder : @obj.Question </legend>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">       //change all the name attributes...
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option1" type="radio" name="Web[@j].Option1" class="form-check-input"  value="r1">
            <label id="WebResult" asp-for="Category2.Option1">1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option2" type="radio" name="Web[@j].Option2" class="form-check-input"  value="r2">
            <label id="WebResult" asp-for="Category2.Option2">2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option3" type="radio" name="Web[@j].Option3" class="form-check-input"  value="r3">
            <label id="WebResult" asp-for="Category2.Option3">3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option4" type="radio" name="Web[@j].Option4" class="form-check-input"  value="r4">
            <label id="WebResult" asp-for="Category2.Option4">4</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input asp-for="Category2.Option5" type="radio" name="Web[@j].Option5" class="form-check-input" value="r5">
            <label id="WebResult" asp-for="Category2.Option5">5</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    j++;   //add this...
}     
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Then you can find the `Web` and `Azure` properties get the selected option with value:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Web { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Category> Azure { get; set; }
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Rena, than you so so much for having a look at this.  I shall give it a try.  Awesome.

Comment: Hi Again, I tried the code but I found that it had a couple of unwanted effects.  I think it was where the naming was different, the Radios then aren't part of a group anymore and so you can pick more than 1 on the same question.  I also found that the label number, when clicked, was changing the first Radio.

Comment: What do you mean for a group? It cannot pick more than 1 on the same question in my side, pls share more details. Also what do you mean for change the first radio? I think maybe your project quite different from mine.

Comment: Hi @GaryLawrie, any update?